# Calculating DCT with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, signal-processing

I'm attempting to use the dct() function in OpenCV to calculate the discrete cosine transform, but I'm getting strange results.

My script is:

```
import os, sys
import cv, cv2
import numpy as np

fn1 = 'original.jpg'
img1 = cv2.imread(fn1, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)

h, w = img1.shape[:2]
vis0 = np.zeros((h,w), np.float32)
vis0[:h, :w] = img1
vis1 = cv2.dct(vis0)
img2 = cv.CreateMat(vis1.shape[0], vis1.shape[1], cv.CV_32FC3)
cv.CvtColor(cv.fromarray(vis1), img2, cv.CV_GRAY2BGR)

cv.ShowImage('',img2)
cv2.waitKey()
cv.SaveImage('saved.jpg', img2)
```

This appears to run without error, but the image shown by ShowImage() and the image saved by SaveImage() appear very different. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any sample images of a DCT-processed image, so I'm not sure which, if either, is correct.

The original image:
[image: original]

The shown DCT image:
[image: shown]

The saved DCT image:
[image: saved]

Why is there such a difference between the shown and saved DCT images? Which is correct?

Comment: Just a guess, but the saved DCT looks to me to be the correct one, and the shown DCT looks like it has somehow lost most of the information (as if all pixels > epsilon have been mapped to 1, for some reason).  Maybe the saved image is in range 0-255 and the shown image has been erroneously clipping that to 0-1.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you displayed the complex output of the DCT. And, because you tried to save a 2-channel image (DCT outputs 2 channels - one for real, one for imaginary part), it saved only the real part (which is somehow close to the magnitude).

So, from your DCT output, use the magnitude() and phase() functions to extract useful info. Display them separately,

And, most important, read carefully about DCT ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform ) so you know what you're doing.

Comment: Where are you getting your information about the output of DCT()? What's written in Wikipedia, and what's actually implemented, are usually very different things. All the OpenCV docs I've found, and even my posted code, show that it returns the same shape as the input array, which for a grayscale image will be a single channel, not two. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#cv-dct

Comment: Look for the opencv refman that comes with the distribution. It's called opencv.pdf or opencv_refman.pdf, depending on the version you're using. It's more detailed than the online reference. And same shape is not equal to same channel number. try cout << matDct.channels(); to solve the mistery :)

Comment: But I have used it, and it gives me 2-channels, floating point, single precision data. As stated in refman

Comment: @vasile...I don't know what to tell you. The code does not lie, and cv2.dct() outputs a numpy ndarray...which does not have a channels() function. Note, I'm using the 2.3 Python wrapper (both cv and cv2) and not the C++ API. Perhaps the recent Python wrapper works differently than what you're used to in the past?

Comment: I do not use python, but, I have used more ocv versions, including 2.3, and 2.3.1. and the images you posted show clearly that there are the complex(first) and real(second) parts of DCT. call magnitude() for the DCT output, and check the result. I should be close to the second image (but not identical).

Comment: And you can also cv.split() the image in two (if there is only one channel, it will throw an error). The two will be the real and imaginary parts. And I think this is what you have to do before calling cv.magnitude()

Answer (score 2):

the saved image is actually the same but the values are clamped to [0..255] and converted to byte (numpy.uint8) before it is saved as JPEG. negative values are set to zero and values above 255 are set to 255.

```
cv2.imshow("before_save", vis1)
vis1[vis1>255] = 255
vis1[vis1<0] = 0
cv2.imshow("saved", vis1.astype(np.uint8))
```